# How can I use list of functions to update the values of a dictionary list?

Tags: python

Let's say I have this list of functions:

```
funcList = [lambda x: int(x)**2, lambda x: int(x)*3]
```

How can I update the values of a list of dictionaries like this:

```
dic = [{'x': '3', 'y': '4'}, {'x': '4', 'y': '5'}]
```

I have tried using lists of comprehension and functions like map but can't seem to make it work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
funcList = [lambda x: int(x)**2, lambda x: int(x)*3]
dic = [{'x': '3', 'y': '4'}, {'x': '4', 'y': '5'}]
new_dic = [{a:f(int(i[a])) for a, f in zip(i, funcList)} for i in dic]
```

Output:

```
[{'x': 9, 'y': 12}, {'x': 16, 'y': 15}]
```